# End-user documentation/explanation of IsInTailPosition() in ES6 Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tail-recursion

I am having no luck in searching for end-user documentation on IsInTailPosition() function in ES6. The [language reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tail-position-calls) explains the algorithm but provides no narrative as to how this function may be used. It is an interesting function as it relates to tail call optimization (if I understand things correctly). Could someone please explain how this function may be used, ideally with an example.

Comment: Do you know what a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) is?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but feel free to include the link in your answer. Please note StackOverflow is a Q&A, not a discussion forum. My question is about the function specifically - it would have been preferrable if you had gone straight ahead and answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language reference is a specification, not meant as end-user documentation. There does not need to be any narrative.

The `IsInTailPosition` algorithm is not a usable function that is available to the end user anyway, it's an *internal* method to determine whether a syntax element is in tail position, and is used to distinguish whether a call expression should get [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimisation or not.

Comment: I do know the reference is a spec, and only mentioned it to indicate my searches were exhaustive. Your answer clears up the issue, thank you. It's actually a shame the function is internal only. I imagined it may be used to detect whether a user function was being tail called, allowing its work to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "*adjust work accordingly*"? The whole point of being eligible for tail call optimisation is that it is not observable from where you are called.

Comment: Going by the name of the function, and not knowing it was internal only, it appeared that it might offer a view into how a user function is called. The point of the function would be to overcome the fact of tail call not being observable to called user function. If what you're saying is that such an insight into a call is impossible, then please consider expanding your answer as the info would be valuable.

Comment: It's not impossible - every debugger will do it by showing you the call (frame) stack, and js has some (outdated) reflection features like `arguments.caller` that make tail call optimisation hard - but I think it's not *useful*. The whole point of writing functions is to be able to call them no matter where, and have them depend on what arguments are passed in but not on the location of the call.